# Need to add data from a column in one table to column comments in another

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, comments, data-dictionary

I'm very new to SQL developer and am now working with an existing Database. The tables do not have column comments and I've been tasked to add them. I created an excel spreadsheet of the column descriptions and imported as a table. I need to write a query for the table with the comments in a column (lets call it Table_1, comments) and insert those comments into the Column Comments for Table_2. If it helps there is a unique column_id number for each comment so comment for Table_1 should be inserted at comment row on Table_2 where Table_1.column_ID = Table_2.column_ID.
Thanks in adavance!

I have tried selecting the column from Table_1 and inserting as Comment on Column in Table_2 and got an error. Also tried reversing the order of these as well. I was able to insert each one individually using:
-Comment on Column table_name.column_name is 'this comment';
But it is tedious and I want to enter all of the comments at once using a query.

Comment: You could have generated all the `comment on ...` statements in your spreadsheet and just copied those into a SQL Developer worksheet, and run as a script.

Comment: Yep, I see that now that you pointed it out. Thanks for the tip! I was told to create the table and then I could query it. So new at this that I didn't attempt to think outside the box- just trying to learn how the pieces fit together.

Answer (score 1):

This is about adding a comment to table's column in data dictionary. To do that, you'll need **dynamic SQL**. Here's an example.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
```

This is table that contains comments you'd want to apply:

```
SQL> select * from comments;

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME  COMMENTS
---------- ------------ ------------------------------
DEPT       DEPTNO       Department ID
DEPT       DNAME        Department name
EMP        SAL          Salary (USD)
```

For example, `DEPT` table currently doesn't have any comments:

```
SQL> select table_name, column_name, comments
  2  from user_col_comments
  3  where table_name = 'DEPT';

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME  COMMENTS
---------- ------------ ------------------------------
DEPT       DEPTNO
DEPT       DNAME
DEPT       LOC
```

Procedure displays command which is then being executed:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(2000);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select table_name, column_name, comments
  5                  from comments
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      l_str := 'comment on column ' || cur_r.table_name ||'.'||
  9        cur_r.column_name || ' is ' || chr(39) || cur_r.comments || chr(39);
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 11      execute immediate l_str;
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
comment on column DEPT.DEPTNO is 'Department ID'
comment on column DEPT.DNAME is 'Department name'
comment on column EMP.SAL is 'Salary (USD)'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select table_name, column_name, comments
  2  from user_col_comments
  3  where table_name = 'DEPT';

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME  COMMENTS
---------- ------------ ------------------------------
DEPT       DEPTNO       Department ID
DEPT       DNAME        Department name
DEPT       LOC

SQL>
```